# Save listBox item to another listBox which is in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I've two View classes. one is DayView and another is CustomView. Both having listboxes. But I want when I entered data in listbox item of CustomView and click on Save button, it should save in DayView listbox. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Bind both view elements (the elements you want to be "connected" with each other) to the same *ViewModel* collection. So if one writes inside the text box, change propagated to the *ViewModel* collection, so notification spreads among subscribers, so to another view too.

Comment: Yes. Both of my View elements inside same View Collection.

Comment: I just want, on click of save button, it sould saved in DayView listBox.

Comment: @Dinesh: non views, but modelview or directly model binded to them has to be the same. In this way they share the same data model, so if it changed by one view, it will reflect those changes in another.

Comment: Isn't it called ViewModel?